# Equivalente de IN() de Sql o InList() de VFP en C#

Tags: c#

Buenos dias, tengo que buscar mediante un FOREACH si un capo contiene alguna de las cadenas.
Ejemplo

```
  foreach (var item in Clientes.Listado)
                {
                    if (item.Nombre.Contains("Juan") || item.Nombre.Contains("Carlos") || item.Nombre.Contains("Pedro")) 
                    {
                        ...Codigo
                    }
                }
```

Me gustaria cambiar `item.Nombre.Contains("Juan") || item.Nombre.Contains("Carlos") || item.Nombre.Contains("Pedro")` 
Por algo mas Prolijo como en FoxPro que seria

```
if INLIST(item.Nombre,"Juan","Carlos","Pedro")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes simplemente meterlos dentro de un array y probar usando `.Any()` si el `item.Nombre` contiene por lo menos uno de los valores del array.

```
if (new [] { "Juan", "Carlos", "Pedro" }.Any(x => item.Nombre.Contains(x))) 
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Que pasa cuando su nombre sea "Juan David" (en `item.Nombre`), ¿Debería considerarlo?

Comment: Según la lógica original debería ser válido porque usa `.Contains()` en lugar de `==`

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba